# How to get product manufacturer swatch image?

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, swatches, manufacturer

I have next string, where I get manufacturer attribute:

```
$brand = $currentProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
```

I need to get attribute swatch image. How can I get it?
[image]

On product filters I got it:

```
                        <img class="object-fit-contain w-100 h-100"  src="<?=
                    $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                            ->getStore()
                            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'attribute/swatch/'.
                    $swatchData['swatches'][$option]['value']?>" alt="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label['label'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab all swatches from attributes

```
$brand_code="manufacturer";
$brandValue = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId())->getData($brand_code);
$swatchHelper=$objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data");
$swatchData = $swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$brandValue]);
```

Displaying image:

```
<img class="object-fit-contain w-100 h-100"  src="<?=
$objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()
    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
    'attribute/swatch'.$swatchData[$brandValue]['value']?>" alt="brand"/>
```